# How can I use Test::NoWarnings to catch redefinition errors for EXPORT()ed subroutines when loading modules in sequence

Tags: perl, unit-testing, warnings

I'm working with a [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::More)-based unit test for part of our codebase that loads all of our in-house modules in sequence with `use_ok()`. I'd like to make warnings fatal to the unit test so that we can more easily catch regressions.

It was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353185/1207563) that I use [Test::NoWarnings](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::NoWarnings), and indeed that seems to be what I am looking for.

The script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use File::Find;
use File::Spec;
use Test::More;
use Test::NoWarnings;


# Determine the filepaths of every .pm file in the lib directory
my @files;
File::Find::find(
    sub
    {
        if (/\.pm$/)
        {
            push(@files, $File::Find::name);
        }
    },
    "$ENV{'CODE_ROOT'}/lib"
);
done_testing(scalar(@files) + 1);

use lib "$ENV{'CODE_ROOT'}/lib";
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    # <code removed for brevity: format file name into Module::Hierarchy::For::Use>
    use_ok($includeString);
}

1;
```

I have come across a few cases in which subroutines `EXPORT()`ed by different modules raise redefinition warnings, but these warnings are not caught by the `Test::NoWarnings` module. In contrast, a warning due to a lower-case attribute declaration is caught correctly.

To be clear, I *have* read the caveats about use of `EXPORT()` vs `EXPORT_OK()`, and the sources of the warnings themselves are being dealt with. I am specifically wondering whether my assumptions about the behaviour of `Test::NoWarnings` are correct, and if so, how I can alter the unit tests so that such things are caught.

Comment: Can you provide two modules, whittled down from your sources, that show the behavior you describe?  Also, what versions of perl and Test:: modules?

Comment: Could it be because you load Test::NoWarning after the warning has alreadu occurred?

Comment: Proof that NoWarnings is able to catch redefinition warnings, just freshly baked by CPAN testers: http://cpantesters.org/cpan/report/c3ec6892-94fa-11e1-9d6f-f6dbfa7543f5

Comment: @ikegami: No, the warnings are definitely coming from the modules loaded by `use_ok()`.

Comment: @pilcrow: Here you go https://gist.github.com/7cbc2b430ec29644af02
(Note that the files should be placed in the same directory - I stripped down the code a bit, but it still shows the same behaviour).

Comment: The versions are as follows:
`perl - 5.8.9 (ActiveState build)`
`Test - 1.25_02`
`Test::More - 0.98`
`Test::NoWarnings - 1.04`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make warnings fatal, what about just turning that on?

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

Yes, the POD for `warnings`pragma does caution strongly against the use of this option:

> FATAL warnings should be used with care, particularly `FATAL => 'all'`

and

> use of FATAL => 'all' is discouraged

But I think use in a regression or unit test is a valid use case.  I've been using this in all of my unit and regression tests for a long time now with no unintended consequences (yet).  I think `Test::Warn` and `Test::NoWarnings` are best used for catching your modules' own warnings, both expected and unexpected.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Test::More;
use Test::Warn;             # test for our own expected warnings                
require Test::NoWarnings;   # REQUIRE to suppress auto test at program exit     

my $tCnt = 0;
ok(1, "first test");                                               $tCnt++;
warning_like { warn("my warn") } (qr/my warn/), "caught warning";  $tCnt++;
ok(1, "made it to the end");                                       $tCnt++;
Test::NoWarnings::had_no_warnings();                               $tCnt++;

done_testing($tCnt);
```

If you throw in a statement like `length("123");` (void context) the compile-time warning will boot you right out with the `FATALS => 'all'`in effect.  Without it, the all the tests run and pass, with no inkling of a potential problem.